# Bamboo losing NuGet packages while trying to test code

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, msbuild, nuget, bamboo

I'm trying to use Bamboo which is running on top of an amazon web server my company has to test a program I wrote using Visual Studio 2013 Community. This program was written in C# and references two NuGet packages, NUnit and FluentAssertions. I commit my code to Bitbucket using SourceTree which automatically triggers a set of tasks on Bamboo.

First it checks out the source code onto the web server. Then it runs the script `nuget restore LayersButtons.sln -NoCache` to restore NUnit and FluentAssertions. Then it runs MSBuild v4.0 (32-bit) to compile my code referencing the project's .sln file.

However, at this point the test fails and generates an error log. The results page says "No failed tests found, a possible compilation error occurred." In the error log it gives me

> warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "FluentAssertions". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk"

and does the same for NUnit. I checked the disk like it said and found out that the script I mentioned which is supposed to restore the nuget packages isn't working because the dlls are missing. I need to fix the NuGet restore so that the dlls are placed where they need to be.

Full error log: http://pastebin.com/246ruJyX